# European network operators mailing list?

Tags: ripe

Can anyone indicate whether RIPE carries a mailing list similar to NANOG's?

Cheers,

Etienne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's many mailing lists available. You will find them in this page:

https://www.ripe.net/participate/mail/ripe-ncc-mailing-lists

Extract:

[image]

There's also some mailing lists for RIPE members:

https://www.ripe.net/participate/mail/ripe-ncc-mailing-lists

Comment: There's a subtle difference. NANOG is a network operator group. RIPE is the regional internet registry (RIR), the equivalent of ARIN. RIPE's mailinglist are a bit more focused on RIPE policies and its application, although there are also lists which are more like NANOG. I'm not aware of any European NOG lists, many countries have a local NOG though (DENOG, UKNOF, DKNOG, NLNOG, etc), at least some of them run mailinglists.

Comment: Indeed. In the second link there's a "ENOG discuss" list for Eurasia Network Operators group  and a "MENOG discuss" list for Middle East Operators Group

Answer (score 0):

Apart from thanking @JFL for his answer, I'd like to add a few bits' worth of information that I've collected since yesterday.

RIPE's support answered with the following information:

> Thank you for your request. The North American Network Operators’ Group is unique in the sense that it includes different countries. In RIPE region the Network operator Groups (NOG) are hosted per country  please find a RIPE labs article that will list them:
> https://labs.ripe.net/nogs/

Indeed, since then, I've subscribed to ITNOG, DENOG and UKNOF.

Sadly, Europe is still too fragmented to present a common operators' group.

Comment: I don’t see that as a bad thing, being able to discuss networking issues on a local scale and in your local language can be very useful. NANOG is much more international than specifically aimed at North America, so a pan-European NOG would resemble NANOG on many points.

Comment: @Teun Vink: You're right in several aspects. It does, for instance, allow regional nuances to emerge (particularly for my purpose, as an academic). The flip side is that you're addressing a smaller audience.